# Why does scanf() return 'L????' when string is null?

Tags: c, scanf

I need to take in user input and store the first 'string' (until whitespace) in a variable called 'cmd' and the rest of the input in a variable called 'input'. Say the user input is '/bin/ls', cmd will take '/bin/ls' but, whereas I would want input to remain null, it prints as 'L????'.

Note that if the user input is '/bin/ls -a', cmd takes '/bin/ls' and input takes '-a' as desired.

```
scanf("%s%[^\n]s", cmd, input);
printf("CMD: %s \nINPUT %s", cmd, input);
```

Could anyone explain why this is? And if possible how I could resolve the problem (e.g is there a way to make '%[^\n]s' only store input if there is input to take?). It's being executed in MINIX if that's any help.

Also it's worth pointing out that I'm pretty new to C Programming.

Comment: You should check the return of `scanf`.

Comment: Don't get into the habit of using `*scanf()` to read *user* input. Your abilities to recover from faulty input, or to avoid buffer overflows, are just too limited. Use `fgets()` and parse in memory.

Comment: Note: The final `"s"` in `"%s%[^\n]s"` serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Your `scanf` call is not writing into `input` if your input string is `"/bin/ls"`, so that `"L????"` must have already been in `input` before the `scanf` call.

In order to find out whether `scanf` read the second token, you can check the return value of [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) : it will return the number of tokens it read successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Heed the [@DevSolar comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805312/why-scanf-returns-l-when-string-is-null#comment55376151_33805312), do not use `*scanf()` to read input.
Better to use `fgets()` (or `getine()`  in *nix) and *then* parse.

`scanf("%s%[^\n]s", cmd, input);` does not check the result value.  This leads to all sorts of trouble as code does not know if input was successful.  [@Zeta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805312/why-scanf-returns-l-when-string-is-null#comment55375959_33805312).

When a partial read occurs, as in OP's case, the remaining values of the destination variables are not changed - this is why code printed `"L????"`.

When the rare input error occurs, the values of the destination variables are not *defined*!

So always check that `*scanf()` completed as desired.

---

Suggested solution:

```
char buf[256];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL) {
  char cmd[sizeof buf];
  char input[sizeof buf];

  switch (sscanf(buf, "%s %[^\n]", cmd, input)) {
    case 2: printf("CMD: %s INPUT %s\n", cmd, input); break; 
    case 1: printf("CMD: %s\n", cmd); break; 
    default: printf("No CMD:\n");
  }
}
```

Note: The final `"s"` in `"%s%[^\n]s"` serves no purpose.  [@ameyCU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33805400/2410359) Drop it.